# Proof of G being a cyclic group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The question is as follows:

Let $G$ be a finite and abelian group that satisfies
$$\#\{g\in G\,\vert\, g^p=e\}\leq p$$
for all $p\in\mathbb{N}$, where $e$ is the identity element in $G$. Prove that $G$ is a cyclic group.

It doesn't seem difficult, but I have hit a wall and I don't know where to start. Any help or hit would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $G$ is not cyclic, you can use the classification of finite abelian groups to show that there is some prime $p$ such that $G$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p\times \Bbb Z_p$.